# Convert a vector to a mask matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, vectorization

Assume we have the following vector:

```
v = np.array([4, 0, 1])
```

The goal is to create the 5 x 3 matrix `M` as follows:

```
[[0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Only one element in each column is equal to 1 for the corresponding index in `v`. For example, since `v[0]` is 4 then `M[4, 0] == 1`, and since `v[2]` is 1 then `M[1, 2] == 1`.

How can I build such a matrix in Python using scipy and numpy? In MATLAB you can do this with the `sparse` and `full` functions in a single line.
I'd prefer not to use a `for` loop since I am looking for a vectorized implementation of this.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the output matrix to be sparse or dense?

Comment: I will use this "M" as a mask matrix for cancel out some values by element-wise multiplication(exp: result=A.*M). The M would be huge ex "100,000x10". So my goal is to use the most optimized one. Either dense or sparse would be fine as long as it is fast and vectorized.

Comment: @superMind, then you probably want a sparse matrix.

Comment: Is `A` sparse or dense?

Comment: A is dense matrix. In each column, I want only cancel out one entry, basically by using the complement of M

Comment: In that case I would expect much better performance when `M` is also dense - you don't want to have to convert between sparse and dense formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dense array output, you could just use two integer arrays to index the rows/cols of the nonzero elements:

```
v = np.array([4, 0, 1])
x = np.zeros((5, 3), np.int)
x[v, np.arange(3)] = 1

print(x)
# [[0 1 0]
#  [0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
from scipy import sparse

inds = np.array([4, 0, 1])
values = np.ones_like(inds)       # [1, 1, 1]
index = np.arange(inds.shape[0])  # 3
m = sparse.csc_matrix((values, (inds, index)), shape=(5, 3))
```

Output:

```
>>> m.todense()
matrix([[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]])
```